# Generate all combinations of list members, repeat X times

Tags: python, combinations

I have list with elements ["0000", "0001"] and i want create repeat them 4 times with all possible pairs.

Ex.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0001
0001 0000 0000 0000
0000 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0001 0000
0001 0001 0001 0001
0001 0001 0001 0000
0001 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0001 0001
```

Already tried all https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html functions but these are not what i want.How can i do that, anyone can help me ?

Solved by @Adam,

```
 list(itertools.product(*([[0, 1]] * 4)))
```

Thanks for everyone helping that fast, love you all.

Comment: Can you please explain your output.

Comment: I suspect `itertools.product` will produce the results you want, although not in the order you've provided them here. Does that matter?

Comment: @Poojan all possible outputs for 4digit, just strings are long you can consider element 0,1 its same thing hope you can understand.

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic of your output.  Why not, for example, `0000 0000 0001 0001`?

Comment: @NPE just edited also this all combinations, i write them with my hands sorry my bad.All combinations basically

Comment: `list(itertools.product(*([[0, 1]] * 4)))`

Comment: @Kevin i tried, with product order doesnt matter can you show me code if you dont mind ?

Comment: @Adam thanks thats exactly what i want man ! thanks so much editing my question right now.

Comment: `list(itertools.product(seq, repeat=4))` is another possible approach.

Comment: @Kevin thanks also, for helping thats really help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using list comprehensions?

```
(x,y) for x in a for y in b
```

Where `a == list[0]` and `b==list[1]`

Repeated four times:

```py
(x,x,y,y) for x in a for y in b
```